# Open Remote Desktop section without prompt for password

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I would like to have a PowerShell script that can start a RD section for a VM that I have on Azure, without the need for a real person to enter the credentials.

I'm not concerned with security. It needs only to be automatic, there is no problem if we have the user and password as plain text.

Using `Get-AzureRMRemoteDesktopFile` I can get the file or use `-Launch` to start with only one line. I also considered `mstsc .\machine.rdp` and edit the file following a similar very old question.

However on both cases I'm prompted with a user and password window.

My client and remote machines are both Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding right, you could try to use the following command to RDP your VM automatic.

```
echo "Connecting to 23.98.218.139"
$Server="23.98.218.139"
$User="user"
$Password="********"
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
```

**Notes: When you first login your VM, you should trust your PC.**

Comment: Thank you. One part is solved. However it would be perfect if i could also bypass the "trust the PC" window.

Comment: @ThadeuAntonioFerreiraMelo Maybe you could check this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b/view/Discussions).

Comment: Thank you Walter. This is a better structured script than mine. Unfortunately it still requires a user to accept the certificate the first time. Fortunately this is only for a prototype and internal testing.